# Using opengl ZBuffer with Libgdx Spritebatch

Tags: java, kotlin, opengl, libgdx

I'm writing a 2d game engine using libgdx where multiple layers of sprites have to be rendered using SpriteBatch with an OrthgraphicCamera. My layers are sorted with a z component : higher z layers should be rendered on top of layers with a lower z.

Currently, I have to render layers sorted by their z component to achieve that. Is there a way, using opengl Z-buffer, to have them rendered out of order, and still show up correctly ?

Comment: [`glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnable.xhtml)?  If it's *not* a case of simply enabling depth testing then I think you'll need to provide more info/context.

Comment: You cannot specify a depth component with SpriteBatch directly. Where do I specify the depth ?

Comment: Ah, okay.  I'm not familiar with `SpriteBatch` -- you might want to add the associated [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spritebatch).

Comment: Not possible if there’s any transparency in the sprite textures. The transparent areas would occlude things behind them if they aren’t drawn in order. Assuming these are all fully opaque sprites that *should* look like opaque rectangles, SpriteBatch cannot batch sprites that are in different Z planes into the same draw call. It can be done with DecalBatch or the third party FlexBatch library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by switching to `DecalBatch` instead of SpriteBatch. Here are the GL commands I use before drawing with the DecalBatch to enable depth-testing :

```kotlin
 Gdx.gl.apply {
            glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
            glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
            glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
            glClearDepthf(1f)
            glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_LESS)
        }
```